# Marklogic keyword search with the apostrophe

Tags: marklogic, apostrophe, marklogic-8

We are use Marklogic 8.0-3, and our database has lots of documents that contain "McDonalds" and "McDonald's". When searching for "McDonalds" or "McDonald's", I expect the same result. But they don't give the same even when I set them to punctuation-insensitive.

```
search:search("McDonalds", 
  <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <term>
      <term-option>case-insensitive</term-option>
      <term-option>diacritic-insensitive</term-option>
      <term-option>punctuation-insensitive</term-option>
    </term>
  </options>
)

search:search("McDonald's", 
  <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <term>
      <term-option>case-insensitive</term-option>
      <term-option>diacritic-insensitive</term-option>
      <term-option>punctuation-insensitive</term-option>
    </term>
  </options>
)
```

For now, the first search query returns 2 results, and the second query returns 79 results. Is there any way to search the keyword and ignore the apostrophe?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to the way words are tokenized in MarkLogic. Whitespace or punctuation separating strings of characters causes those characters to be parsed as separate tokens. In your question:

```
xdmp:describe(cts:tokenize("McDonald's"))
=>
(cts:word("McDonald"), cts:punctuation("'"), cts:word("s"))
```

`McDonald's` is treated as a phrase made up of two word tokens separated by a punctuation token. When you invoke the `punctuation-insensitive` option, it will ignore punctuation, but it will not join tokens to do so. For example:

```
cts:contains("McDonald+=?%s", cts:word-query("McDonald's", "punctuation-insensitive"))
=>
true

cts:contains("McDonalds", cts:word-query("McDonald's", "punctuation-insensitive"))
=>
false
```

If you only have a limited number of words like this, I recommend using the [thesaurus functions that ship with MarkLogic](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/thesaurus) to expand searches for either term.

It's also possible to [create override rules for MarkLogic's tokenizer](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/custom-tokenization), such that you could remove apostrophes in the index; however, you may still be on the hook for sanitizing search input, and there may be other unintended side-effects of doing that, depending on your application.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's happening:

```
xdmp:describe(cts:tokenize("McDonald's"))
```

shows that the term gets broken down into

```
(cts:word("McDonald"), cts:punctuation("'"), cts:word("s"))
```

So we see that the single quote is a punctuation term and that the "s" is a separate word. The tokenization happens the same for both data ingest and the query. The question is whether these two things should match:

- (cts:word("McDonald"), cts:punctuation("'"), cts:word("s"))
- cts:word("McDonalds")

They don't, as you might guess. The punctuation gets ignored here, but that still leaves us trying to match "McDonald" followed by "s" against "McDonalds." I don't think any set of options is going to fix this.

I've got three ideas for you on how you might address this.

1. on data load, apply the envelope pattern. From `<fast-food>McDonalds</fast-food>`, add `<fast-food>McDonald's</fast-food>`.

Suppose your original doc is

```
<doc>
  <fast-food>McDonalds</fast-food>
</doc>
```

You could apply a transform to make it like this instead:

```
<envelope>
  <meta>
    <fast-food>McDonald's</fast-food>
  </meta>
  <doc>
    <fast-food>McDonalds</fast-food>
  </doc>
</envelope>
```

Now searching on "McDonald's" will match this document.

2. use semantics to track that "McDonalds" and "McDonald's" are the same thing and do run-time query expansion (at run time, do a SPARQL query to see whether there are any synonyms for the terms in your search; if so, expand the search with those terms)
3. use the [Thesaurus functionality](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/thesaurus#id_28692) to do run-time query expansion